# Cloudinary Private type for django

Tags: django, cloudinary

Cloudinary is working fine with Django but not sure how to change all the file types to private?

Apparently i can define type but where do I do that? The default file storage is defined in setting
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'cloudinary_storage.storage.MediaCloudinaryStorage'

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a model with CloudinaryField according to https://cloudinary.com/documentation/django_integration